# How to find element with li class inside span class in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

[image]Its name of tab. I have tried by Link-text but it's not working.

I have tried `d.findElement(By.linkText("Clauses")).click();`
It shows error

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link
>   text","selector":"Clauses"}

[image]

Comment: //span[contains(text(), 'Clause')], can you try this XPath please, Is there a chance the element to be in iFrame.

Comment: I think you need to consider the selector you are using. You have tried with class `title` which may be present in other parts of the DOM and so it may not work as expected. As suggested by others, try css or xpath selectors. You can try `d.findElement(By.className("clauses")).click()` to click on Clauses or `d.findElement(By.className("myAssignedRequests")).click()` to click on My Assigned Requests

Comment: Thank you all for your help! It worked .It was iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Whole web page is frame. So first I switched to frame & then performed actions

```java
d.switchTo().frame("frame-8_SNb34A224IASwxX0yc");
d.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='tabviewMainContainerLexApp']/div/ul/li[11]/a/span")).click(); //click on tab using X-path
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `byXpath` to find element using xPath expressions. To get the link you should use the following:

```
//li[@class='uwa-tab clauses']/a[@href='#clauses']
```

To go further to get the `span`:

```
//li[@class='uwa-tab clauses']/a[@href='#clauses']/span[.='Clauses']
```

or a simplified one without the `classes`:

```
//li/a/span[.='Clauses']
```

If you want to find the link (`<a>..</a>`) and you want to filter only by the title you could use:

```
//li/a/span[.='Clauses']/..
```

This one locates the `span` by its text and then steps back to its parent by the `/..`.

Also there are many more possibilities, this [locator table cheat-sheat](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/Locators_table_1_0_2.pdf) summarizes them quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you simply select the anchor tag

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Clauses')]")).click();
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help! It worked .It was iframe